# PHP not finding class in required file

Tags: php, wrapper, json-rpc

I am using this php wrapper for multichain's json rpc api: https://github.com/Kunstmaan/libphp-multichain in a php file.

The error I see in apache error log is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MultichainClient' not found in /var/www/html/new.php on line 5

I'm not sure how I should adjust my code and the wrapper looks:
My code:

```
<?php
       require_once 'libphp-multichain/src/be/kunstmaan/multichain/MultichainClient.php';
       require_once 'libphp-multichain/src/be/kunstmaan/multichain/MultichainHelper.php';
       $client = new MultichainClient("http://107.170.46.124:port",{usr},{pwd});
       print_r($client);
</code>
```

[MultichainClient.php Code](https://github.com/Kunstmaan/libphp-multichain/blob/master/src/be/kunstmaan/multichain/MultichainClient.php)

Answer (score 1):

The "MultichainClient" class is namespaced. You need to use the namespace as well as the class name when "calling" the class.

```
$client = new be\kunstmaan\multichain\MultichainClient();
```